# SSIS double precision prob

Tags: ssis

I am facing prob with double precision. I have numeric records upto 15 digit after decimal place.I am using double-precision float [DT-R8] data conversion before moving data into ms database. Prob is here that I am able to see only 12 digit after decimal place and remaining getting truncated after moving to DB. Eg. if my data is 72.6610932197542 in excel its getting inserted into db as 72.661093219754.

Is their any other alternative for this to move correct decimal digit record to database from excel.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just an Excel field format that is set to show reduced precision? Many tools don't show complete precision because lower-order bits often turn to noise after successive operations, and the accuracy is reduced.

Comment: Excel field format for that column in general. while clicking on that cell it will show complete digit number on function textbox.

Comment: What data type is the target column in your DB? Does the truncation occur in the package, did you check this with a data viewer? Or does the truncation happen when you insert the data to the DB?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start troubleshooting by adding a dataviewer to the output from the Excel source, and checking how many decimal places are present in the dataflow. Also double-check you have enough precision in the target column.